# Custom components in OneDrive for Business

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, onedrive-for-business

Can i Add Custom columns like TaskCompletedDate and AssignedTo for Collaboration purpose in One Drive for Business, where Enduser can enter TaskcompletedDate so that Email should automatically trigger to AssignedTo Members .